# Merge Pandas Column based on Conditions

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, join, merge

Suppose that I have 2 pandas data frame the first one is a look up table and the second one is a data table which needs to be populated with an additional column `Category` which will be extracted from look up table using 2 conditions. The Region should match and the distance should be minimum. Both the data frames can be generated using code below.

```
lookup_data = {'Category' : ['A1', 'A2', 'B1', 'C1', 'D1', 'D2'],
               'Region':['A', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'D'],
                'Distance':[109, 200, 300, 400, 500, 600]}
lookup_data_df = pd.DataFrame(lookup_data)

actual_data = {'Region':['A', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'D', 'E'],
               'Distance':[95, 199, 10, 350, 550, 560, 200]}
actual_df = pd.DataFrame(actual_data)
```

I want a solution without using loops. The expected output data frame can be generated using code below.

```
expected_data = {'Region':['A', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'D', 'E'],
               'Category' : ['A1', 'A2', 'B1', 'C1', 'D1', 'D2', 'A2'],
               'Distance':[95, 199, 10, 350, 550, 560, 200]}
expected_data_df = pd.DataFrame(expected_data)
```

Edit: In case of unseen region for example region `E` disregard the region and just choose `Category` with minimum distance that is `A2` in current scenario.

Comment: Can you show what the expected result should be if the sample `lookup_data` has `'Region':['A', 'B', 'B', 'C', 'C', 'D']` (regions not matched) ?

Comment: You can pick category with the shortest distance in that case disregarding the `Region`

Comment: still, what should be the final `'Category'` list (in your vision) for the mentioned `'Region':['A', 'B', 'B', 'C', 'C', 'D']` ?

Comment: `'Category' : ['A1', 'B1', 'B1', 'C1', 'C1', 'D2']`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC, you can perform a *double* [`merge_asof`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.merge_asof.html) :

```
def min_distance(data, lookup, match=None, key="Distance"):
  return pd.merge_asof(
      actual_df.sort_values(key),
      lookup_data_df.sort_values(key),
      by=match, on=key, direction="nearest"
  )

out = (
    min_distance(actual_df, lookup_data_df, match="Region")
      .pipe(lambda df_: df_.fillna(
          {"Category": min_distance(df_, lookup_data_df)["Category"]}))
      .sort_values("Region", ignore_index=True)
      [["Region", "Category", "Distance"]]
) # the last two chains could be optional though
```

Output :

```
#expected_data_df.equals(out) is True

print(out)

  Region Category  Distance
0      A       A1        95
1      A       A2       199
2      B       B1        10
3      C       C1       350
4      D       D1       550
5      D       D2       560
6      E       A2       200
```

Answer (score 1):

Another possible solution, which is based on [pandas.merge](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html):

```
df = pd.merge(lookup_data_df, actual_df, on='Region', suffixes=('_', ''),
              how='right')
idx = df.index[df.isna().any(axis=1)]
df.loc[idx, 'Category'] = [lookup_data_df.loc[
    (df.loc[x,'Distance']-lookup_data_df['Distance']).abs().idxmin(), 'Category']
                           for x in idx]

(df.fillna(0).assign(d = lambda x: (x.Distance - x.Distance_).abs())
 .groupby(['Region', 'Category'], as_index=False)
 .apply(lambda x: x.loc[x['d'].idxmin(), :])
 .drop(['d', 'Distance_'], axis=1))
```

Output:

```
  Category Region  Distance
0       A1      A        95
1       A2      A       199
2       B1      B        10
3       C1      C       350
4       D1      D       550
5       D2      D       560
6       A2      E       200
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by merging the two data frames on the `'Region'` column and then computing the difference between the 'Distance' values of the two data frames. Finally, for each `'Region'`, you can find the row with the minimum difference and select the corresponding `'Category'` value from the `lookup_data_df`.

```
import pandas as pd

lookup_data = {'Category' : ['A1', 'A2', 'B1', 'C1', 'D1', 'D2'],
               'Region':['A', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'D'],
                'Distance':[109, 200, 300, 400, 500, 600]}
lookup_data_df = pd.DataFrame(lookup_data)

actual_data = {'Region':['A', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'D'],
               'Distance':[95, 199, 10, 350, 550, 560]}
actual_df = pd.DataFrame(actual_data)

# Merge the two data frames on the 'Region' column
merged_df = actual_df.merge(lookup_data_df, on='Region', suffixes=('_actual', '_lookup'))

# Compute the absolute difference between the 'Distance' values
merged_df['diff'] = abs(merged_df['Distance_actual'] - merged_df['Distance_lookup'])

# Sort the merged_df by 'diff' and then group by 'Region' and take the first row
result = merged_df.sort_values(by='diff').groupby('Region').first().reset_index()

# Drop unnecessary columns and rename the columns
result = result[['Region', 'Category', 'Distance_actual']]
result.columns = ['Region', 'Category', 'Distance']

print(result)
```

expected output:

```
  Region Category  Distance
0      A       A1        95
1      A       A2       199
2      B       B1        10
3      C       C1       350
4      D       D1       550
5      D       D2       560
```